# How to integrate Genexus 18 with Authorize.Net Payment API

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to integrate Authorize.net payment API in my KB. I guess it would have to be an external object, however, I'm not to sure how to implement it. I see there is an [C# SDK](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet), what is the best way of importing this SDK

I tried using the .Net import tool:

[API Document](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html)